# Print the validation loss in each epoch in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I want to print the model's validation loss in each epoch, what is the right way to get and print the validation loss?

Is it like this:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean')
for x, y in validation_loader:
 optimizer.zero_grad()
 out = model(x)
 loss = criterion(out, y)
 loss.backward()
 optimizer.step()
 losses += loss

display_loss = losses/len(validation_loader)
print(display_loss)
```

or like this

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean')
for x, y in validation_loader:
     optimizer.zero_grad()
     out = model(x)
     loss = criterion(out, y)
     loss.backward()
     optimizer.step()
     losses += loss
    
display_loss = losses/len(validation_loader.dataset)
print(display_loss)
```

or something else? Thank you.

Comment: don't you EVER NEVER backprop using validation/test data!!!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NO!!!!**
[image]

Under no circumstances should you train your model (i.e., call `loss.backward()` + `optimizer.step()`)  using validation / test data!!!

If you want to validate your model:

```py
model.eval()  # handle drop-out/batch norm layers
loss = 0
with torch.no_grad():
  for x,y in validation_loader:
    out = model(x)  # only forward pass - NO gradients!!
    loss += criterion(out, y)
# total loss - divide by number of batches
val_loss = loss / len(validation_loader)
```

Note how `optimizer` has nothing to do with evaluating the model on the validation set.
You do not change the model according to the validation data - only validate it.

Comment: Ah, sorry I just learn deep learning, and thank you.

Comment: @rubiks - the main thing here is that you understand WHY you must not backprop using validation data

Comment: There is a small mistake :)
It should be loss += criterion(out, y)